# SQL Query from SQL novice

Tags: sql

I am trying to generate several spreadsheets, sourcing the data from an SQL database. I am new to SQL. The only tool I have for accessing the database is MS Query.
I have managed a lot by the copy & modify process, but now am stuck. I have the following code which allows me to select values from a specified Ac for a specified period.

```
SELECT Table1.Date, Table1.Ac, Table1.Ref, Table1.Text, Table1.Value
FROM Main.dbo.Table1 Table1
WHERE (Table1.Ac=?) AND (Table1.Date>=? And Table1.Date<=?)
ORDER BY Table1.Date
```

What I now want to do is:

- Delete the Table1.Ac criterium so that I get all records between selected dates
- Group by the Table1.Ac field, sorted ascending
- In a new column, Display the sum of all the values for each Table1.Ac

This would be very similar to a Summary TB in accounts parlance

As soon as I start modifying the code, I get the message: `Parameters are not allowed in queries that can't be displayed graphically`.

I would appreciate any help on the SQL code, and on any better tools that I can integrate into Excel.   The company is standardising on SQL and converting all its old databases (Access, Accounts, Btrieve, etc) into SQL

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend working in SQL Server Management Studio if using Microsoft SQL Server.

Does this query suffice?

```
SELECT Table1.Ac, Sum(Table1.Value)
FROM Main.dbo.Table1 Table1
WHERE (Table1.Date>=? And Table1.Date<=?)
ORDER BY Table1.Date GROUP BY Table1.Ac
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link outlining using MS Query to get data into Excel..

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/use-microsoft-query-to-retrieve-external-data-HA010099664.aspx